# Quickly degrading stream throughput with chained operations?

Tags: java, java-stream, throughput

I expected that simple intermediate stream operations, such as `limit()`, have very little overhead. But the difference in throughput between these examples is actually significant:

```
final long MAX = 5_000_000_000L;

LongStream.rangeClosed(0, MAX)
          .count();
// throughput: 1.7 bn values/second


LongStream.rangeClosed(0, MAX)
          .limit(MAX)
          .count();
// throughput: 780m values/second

LongStream.rangeClosed(0, MAX)
          .limit(MAX)
          .limit(MAX)
          .count();
// throughput: 130m values/second

LongStream.rangeClosed(0, MAX)
          .limit(MAX)
          .limit(MAX)
          .limit(MAX)
          .count();
// throughput: 65m values/second
```

I am curious: What is the reason for the quickly degrading throughput? Is it a consistent pattern with chained stream operations or my test setup? (I did not use JMH so far, just set up a quick experiment with a stopwatch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`limit` will result in a *slice* being made of the stream, with a *split iterator* (for parallel operation). In one word: inefficient. A large overhead for a no-op here. And that two consecutive `limit` calls result in two slices is a shame.

You should take a look at the implementation of `IntStream.limit`.

As Streams are still relative new, optimization should come last; when production code exists. Doing limit 3 times seems a bit far-fetched.

Comment: So this is just a question of sub-optimal implementation...? Is there any workaround? We have to admit that the overhead is impressive (as impressive as `limit (x3)` is far-fetched or artificial)

Comment: Chained stream expression tend to be expressive without much overhead, so it is a matter of smart data structures and algorithms. As soon as you see something more complex, with grouping for instance, there might be simpler data structures to avoid such structural processing. So _no_, there is no special medicin.

Comment: @JoopEggen the only medicine is in the Stream implementation itself, I guess

Comment: @Eugene I have seen Stream code with grouping / a temporary list / flatMap, that just as well could be done by a much simpler, more direct Stream snippet using references to variables (AtomicInteger). Grouping itself is nice, not bad, but Streams are not as declarative as SQL or functional languages, where under the hood strong optimizations may happen.

Comment: @JoopEggen I also tried this with `sequential()` in front, following the [Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) guidance to enforce the cheapest execution path - no effect though.Limiting 3 times is probably far-fetched. Two calls might be realistic if the stream operations are scattered across different application layers and there are map/filter operations in the middle. In the end I was impressed with the significant drop in performance and curious about the cause.

Comment: @JoopEggen this is not an issue of the API design. We have an alternative implementation in use (a Java 7 compatible back-port), which does not suffer from these issues at all. There, applying `limit` directly after `rangeClosed` has the same effect as if you used the adapted range in the first place. Likewise, multiple subsequent `limit` operations would work as if you did one `limit` with the smallest number only. However, I still don’t have the feeling that this difference has much relevance in practice. What matters more, is avoiding these overly long call chains (avoid the inlining limit)

Answer (score 4):

This is an under implementation in the Stream API (don't know how to call it otherwise).

In the first example, you *know* the `count` without actually counting - there are no `filter` (for example) operations that might clear the internal flag called `SIZED`.  It's actually a bit interesting if you change this and inspect:

```
System.out.println(
            LongStream.rangeClosed(0, Long.MAX_VALUE)
                    .spliterator()
                    .hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED)); // reports false

System.out.println(
            LongStream.rangeClosed(0, Long.MAX_VALUE - 1) // -1 here
                    .spliterator()
                    .hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED)); // reports true
```

And `limit` - even if there are no fundamental (AFAIK) limitations, does not introduce `SIZED` flag:

```
System.out.println(LongStream.rangeClosed(0, MAX)
            .limit(MAX)
            .spliterator()
            .hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED)); // reports false
```

Since you count everywhere, the fact that internally the Stream API does not know if stream is `SIZED`, it just counts; while if the Stream is `SIZED` - reporting count would be well, instant.

When you add `limit` a few times, you are just making it worse, since it has to limit those limits, every single time.

Things have improved in java-9 for example, for the case:

```
System.out.println(LongStream.rangeClosed(0, MAX)
            .map(x -> {
                System.out.println(x);
                return x;
            })
            .count());
```

In this case `map` is not computed at all, since there is no need for it to - no intermediate operation changes the size of the stream.

Theoretically a Stream API might see that you are `limit`ing and 1) introduce the `SIZED` flag 2) see that you have multiple calls of `limit` and just probably take the last one. *At the moment* this is not done, but this has a very limited scope, how many people would abuse `limit` this way? So don't expect any improvements on this part soon.

Comment: An interesting detail and good to know that things are optimized with later Java releases. But the real cause should be somewhere else since `limit()` (at least in theory) is an extremely cheap operation and calling it 3 times should not cause a drop of performance in the range of 1-2 orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Matthias why do you think the would be an extremely cheap operation? As far as I can see from the implementation it checks the `limit`, every time, before handing that element further. that would be a lot of checks; but also it might very well be the way you testing this

Comment: Because the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) hinted in that direction plus I let myself deceive by the more-than-linear drop in thoughput (and also was hoping for CPU optimizations to kick in on the extremely predictable execution pattern during the looping/iteration). After a brief test with dedicated iterator-based limiting I see similar results as with streams. So my initial assumptions were obviously unrealistic.

Comment: @Matthias it would be very cool if you actually showed your tests, I assume JMH based?